# How many even number in a sequence are there?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> How many even numbers in the below numbers ?
>
> $$\binom{k}{0},\binom{k}{1},\binom{k}{2},\ldots,\binom{k}{k}$$

Worng: <strike>Is it true that all of them are odd iff $k$ is odd, and if $k$ is even then $\binom{k}{2i}$ is odd, $\binom{k}{2i+1}$ is even. ?</strike>

Comment: Is $ \binom{5}{2} $ even or odd?

Comment: Your iff is false in both directions.

Comment: Related challenge: As you take more and more rows of Pascal's triangle, what fraction of the entries are even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on Pascal's Triangle:

> Parity: To count odd terms in row $n$, convert $n$ to binary. Let $x$ be the 
>   number of ones in the binary representation. Then number of odd terms
>   will be $2^x$.

A concise proof can be found [here](http://coco-m.web.lynchburg.edu/Teaching/Gov%20School%202011/Odd%20Coefficients.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

They're all odd iff K+1 is a power of 2.